# Similarity measure over time

Tags: time-series, independence, similarities

I'm completely new to this so I apologise in advance if my question isn't even phrased correctly.

I want to analyse changes in similarity of two interacting entities over time. Each entity is represented as a 100-D feature vector which is updated interchangeably after every interaction. My hypothesis is that the similarity would increase over time, as the entities interact. Are there any parametric tests that could handle it, given that the samples are non-independent? Would it make sense to simply measure euclidean distance between the features at every time step and then somehow analyse how it changes over time?

Thank you in advance!